# how to get number of days between consecutive records in table?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datediff

In MySQL, I have a table with several columns, one of them being a date column.
I want to be able to make a query so i can get an additional column showing the number of days between the current date (the date for each row) and the date of the previous row.

The order of records is by date, and I filter by other column.

e.g.

```
id  other_col   date        days_between_dates
1   abc     2013-05-01      0
2   abc     2013-05-07      6
3   abc     2013-05-09      2
4   abc     2013-05-19      10
5   abc     2013-05-25      6
6   abc     2013-06-03      9
7   abc     2013-06-14      11
```

Obviously since the first row has nothing to compare to, it should show `0`.

I know i can get the diff between two dates with the `datediff` MySQL function, e.g.

```
select datediff('2013-06-03','2013-05-25');
```

My basic query is `select * from mytable where other_col = 'something' order by date;`
but how can i make a query to directly obtain a result like in the example ? (I need the extra "`days_between_dates`" column).

Also note that usually the id's are ordered, and without gaps, but i cannot guarantee that. only that i will sort by ascending date, and filtering by the "other_col" column.

Comment: Are the id's in the table guaranteed to be sequential (i.e. they are autoincrement values and you don't ever delete rows or change the autoincrement value)?

Comment: yes, they are sequiential, but i don't know if there can be deleted, thus generating "gaps" in the IDs.  Ideally (and all the cases I've seen), the id's are always sequential and without gaps, but maybe not always . For this case, let's just assume they are indeed sequential.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something along these lines:

```
SELECT T.id, 
       T.other_col, 
       T.yourdate, 
       IFNULL(datediff(T.yourdate,(select MAX(TT.yourdate) 
                                   FROM yourtable TT 
                                   WHERE TT.yourdate < T.yourdate 
                                   AND TT.other_col = 'abc')),0)
FROM yourtable T
where other_col = 'abc';
```

You can see it in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4559/2/0)

This works by calculating the difference between the current record's date (`T.date`) and the date that is the biggest (`MAX(TT.date)`) of the one's that are smaller than the current record's date ( `WHERE TT.date < T.date` ).

When there is no smaller date, there's the COALESCE to make it be 0, instead of null.

Edit. added coalesce to give 0 in the first line

Comment: it seems to work! Would you mind explaining it further? specially the inner select within the datediff's second argument, and why to use MAX date.

Comment: Update, it doesn't work when i have several different "other_col" values, and their dates are non consecutive between them, [see this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdef8/1/0). I guess i just need to add the `where` condition to both selects. Let me try.

Comment: Yes. you have to, otherwise the inner query is going to check in the entire table for the date that is the biggest date that is smaller than the current record's date. If you put the where in the inner query it will work like you want it.
About the way this works, i'll update my answer with a small explanation.

Comment: Thanks, if you don't mind, also add the `where`s in the answer, so other people can see them regardless the comments, and the same for the fiddle (so if I accept it, it is a full answer) =). Also, instead of that "coalesce" function, i would have used ifnull(), which is more human readable. Thanks again!

Comment: I made an [updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4559/2/0) with a more complete example with more values and the complete query

Comment: Done. You may want to update your question too to put some records with other_col = 'def', and add the sql tag, so people can find it easier.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to suggest an alternative to the answer given above.  If you can guarantee that the id's are sequential, you can join the table to itself to get the result you are looking for:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.other_col, t1.date, DATEDIFF(t2.date,t1.date)
FROM table AS t1
LEFT_JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id - 1
```

Note that I use a LEFT JOIN here such that the first row and last rows on t1 (the main table) will be present.