# MySQL query rows with defined date interval

Tags: php, mysql

I have no idea how to solve the following problem: I have several rows in my database with one timestamp per row. Now I would like to filter all rows for entries until the date interval for **any two dates** is bigger than 30 days. **I have no defined date interval for specific dates**, like between 12/01/2017 and 11/01/2017, that would be easy, even for me. All I know is that the timestamp interval from one row to the next row (query must be sorted by timestamp desc) must not be bigger than 30 days.

Please see my db at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55a521/2 
In this case the last entry shown should be the one with id **65404844**. I would appreciate if you might give me a small hint for this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is hard-to-impossible for (pure) SQL to refer to a preceding or succeeding record to compare with. I guess a script would make your life much easier.

Comment: question may sound simple but if you post records you have and expected records out of them, that would help someone solve your issue

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far. I have added an example of rows to my question.

Comment: might be easier to filter the recordset in php

Comment: Well, you could have searched on SO a little bit... A question that tells you how to determine the number of days between a record and the next one based on a timestamp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005601/how-to-get-number-of-days-between-consecutive-records-in-table Here is another one that shows how to select records created 1 seconds apart (yeah, it is for postgresql, not MySQL, but the principles are the same): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550407/selecting-all-records-created-less-than-1-second-apart These should give you enough ideas to start.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Your comment seems a little inaccurate and, as such, a little unconstructive.

Comment: @vloryan Add the desired result, please. Your question isn't clear and I wasted my time so far. Thanks.

Comment: @vloryan Does _previous entry_ refer to the preceding row, or to the youngest entry of the already selected rows?

Comment: The preceding one. Thank you so much for trying!

Comment: I have added my db to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55a521/2. In this case the last entry shown should be the one with id **65404844**

Comment: @PhilippMaurer Then feel free to remove the downvote.

Comment: @vloryan My query produces your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to build a filter.

```
SELECT
t.id,
from_unixtime(timestamp)
, IF(@pt < timestamp - 30*24*60*60, 1, 0) AS filter
, @pt := timestamp
FROM
t
, (SELECT @pt := MIN(timestamp) FROM t) v
ORDER BY timestamp
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55a521/22/0)

Important here is to order by timestamp. Then you initialize the `@pt` variable with the lowest value. Another important thing is to have the select clause in the right order.

First you compare the current record with the variable in the `IF()` function. Then you assign the current record to the variable. This way when the next row is evaluated, the variable still holds the value of the previous row in the `IF()` function.

To get the rows you want, use above query in a subquery to filter.

```
SELECT id, ts FROM (
    SELECT
    t.id,
    from_unixtime(timestamp) as ts
    , IF(@pt < timestamp - 30*24*60*60, 1, 0) AS filter
    , @pt := timestamp
    FROM
    t
    , (SELECT @pt := MIN(timestamp) FROM t) v
    ORDER BY timestamp
) sq 
WHERE sq.filter = 1
```

Comment: 30*24*60*60 is clearer,  but 2592000 may be fractionally faster.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55a521/28 does not give me any results :(

Comment: You have to replace the table name with the correct one. Try this link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55a521/30/0

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! So, how can I have this one result as the last result? I need all rows up until this one shown in your fiddle. So the one with ID 65404844 must be the last one.

Comment: All rows until this particular one? Then try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55a521/34/0

Answer (score -1):

This filters out the rows that have a more than 30 days difference from the previous rows. (1st solution) - only works if the id column has consecutive values

```
SELECT t.id, t.timestamp, DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp), FROM_UNIXTIME(t.timestamp)) AS days_diff
FROM tbl t
LEFT JOIN tbl t1 
    ON t.id = t1.id + 1
HAVING days_diff <= 30    
ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC;
```

This filters all the results that are within 30 days of each of the other entries.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl t
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT id
   FROM tbl t1
   WHERE DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp), FROM_UNIXTIME(t.timestamp)) < 30
   AND   t1.id <> t.id
   )
ORDER BY t.timestamp desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for supporting my topic! But your answer refers to two tables, right? I need to filter the rows within one table only.

Comment: Whoops, corrected my query. No, it actually refers to one single table and you inner join it with itself.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer It's okay, it wasn't clear enough anyway. I've put both queries now, for whoever may want them. Thanks man.

Comment: THANKS! I have added my db to sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55a521/2. In this case the last entry shown should be the one with id 65404844